# Old anime about a green-haired man with a sword and two girls

Tags: story-identification, anime

I forgot the name of this old funny anime. It was about the adventures of a man with green hair and a sword and two girls. I think one of a girls is "mage" and the man would shout his name when he punched his enemies. I think the first letter of his name was "R" and he shouted something like "Rouin Punch!"

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I had some difficulty interpreting this description, so if I edited anything incorrectly, please edit the question yourself to fix it. Also, please let us know the approximate year in which you watched this.

Comment: See if anything here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/CallingYourAttacks/AnimeAndManga